# Group a List of Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have some JSON data coming from the API as a list of dictionaries, such as:

```
entities = [
    {'name': 'McDonalds', 'city': 'New York', 'gross': 250000000, 'id': '000001'},
    {'name': 'McDonalds', 'city': 'Philadelphia', 'gross': 190000000, 'id': '000002'},
    {'name': 'Shake Shack', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'gross': 17000000, 'id': '000003'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Houston', 'gross': 23000000, 'id': '000004'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'gross': 12000000, 'id': '000005'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Dallas', 'gross': 950000, 'id': '000006'},
]
```

I'm trying to group all the entries with the same name into another list of dictionaries named for whatever business it is.

```
def group_entities(entities):

    entity_groups = []

    # Establish a blank list for each unique name
    for entity in entities:
        entity['name'] = []
        entity_groups.append(entity['name'])

    # Within each business's list, add separate dictionaries with details
    for entity in entities:
        entity['name'].append({
            'name':entity['name'],
            'city':entity['city'],
            'gross':entity['gross'],
            'id':entity['id']
            })

    entity_groups.extend(entity['name'])

    return entity_groups
```

I can't use `entity['name']` as a variable name because it just changes the original value nor can I use a string version of the name. I want to end up with data I can iterate and display like:

```
Business
  • All City 1 Dictionary Values 
  • All City 2 Dictionary Values, etc
Business
  • All City 1 Dictionary Values 
  • All City 2 Dictionary Values, etc
```

I'm at a loss as to how to even do further research on this because I don't know proper 'googleable' terms to describe what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you add what the output should look like?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is ordered by name:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

entities = [
    {'name': 'McDonalds', 'city': 'New York', 'gross': 250000000, 'id': '000001'},
    {'name': 'McDonalds', 'city': 'Philadelphia', 'gross': 190000000, 'id': '000002'},
    {'name': 'Shake Shack', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'gross': 17000000, 'id': '000003'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Houston', 'gross': 23000000, 'id': '000004'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'gross': 12000000, 'id': '000005'},
    {'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'city': 'Dallas', 'gross': 950000, 'id': '000006'},
]
data =  [{k: list(v)}  for k, v in groupby(entities, itemgetter("name"))]
```

Which would give you:

```
[{'McDonalds': [{'id': '000001', 'city': 'New York', 'name': 'McDonalds', 'gross': 250000000}, {'id': '000002', 'city': 'Philadelphia', 'name': 'McDonalds', 'gross': 190000000}]}, {'Shake Shack': [{'id': '000003', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'name': 'Shake Shack', 'gross': 17000000}]}, {'In-N-Out Burger': [{'id': '000004', 'city': 'Houston', 'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'gross': 23000000}, {'id': '000005', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'gross': 12000000}, {'id': '000006', 'city': 'Dallas', 'name': 'In-N-Out Burger', 'gross': 950000}]}]
```

Or if you don't want the name:

```
 keys = ("id","gross", "city")

 data = [{k: [dict(zip(keys, itemgetter(*keys)(dct))) for dct in v]}  for k, v in groupby(entities, itemgetter("name"))]
```

If the data is not ordered you can use a *defaultdict*:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for entity in entities:
    d[entity["name"]].append(dict(entity))
print([{k: v} for k,v in d.items()])
```

Again you cab remove the name or maybe you wan to use the original dicts and you don't mind mutating  them :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for entity in entities:
    d[entity.pop("name")].append(entity)
print([{k: v} for k,v in d.items()])
```

That will give you:

```
[{'Shake Shack': [{'id': '000003', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'gross': 17000000}]}, {'McDonalds': [{'id': '000001', 'city': 'New York', 'gross': 250000000}, {'id': '000002', 'city': 'Philadelphia', 'gross': 190000000}]}, {'In-N-Out Burger': [{'id': '000004', 'city': 'Houston', 'gross': 23000000}, {'id': '000005', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'gross': 12000000}, {'id': '000006', 'city': 'Dallas', 'gross': 950000}]}]
```

It all depends on whether you want to use the original dicts again and/or if you want the names kept in the dicts. You can combine parts of the logic to get whatever format you like.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def group_entities(entities):

    entity_groups = {}

    # Within each business's list, add separate dictionaries with details
    for entity in entities:
        name = entity['name']   # name is the key for entity_groups
        del entity['name']      # remove it from each entity
        # add the entity to the entity_groups with the key (name)
        entity_groups[name] = entity_groups.get(name, []) + [entity]

    return entity_groups
```

If you want to keep the entity name in each entity, remove the `del` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
bycompany = {}
for ent in entities:
    if not ent['name'] in bycompany:
        # if there is no location list for this company name,
        # then start a new list for this company.
        bycompany[ent['name']] = []

    # Add the dict to the list of locations for this company.
    bycompany[ent['name']].append(ent)
```

Comment: The use of `defaultdict` will make it a three-liner: `bycompany = defaultdict(list); for ent in entities: bycompany[ent'name'].append(ent)`